# How to identify the correct class for Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn Scrapping , one problem I am facing is identifying correct class names , is there any particular rule/method to follow for identifying correct class names For Example in the code below I am trying to get Questions lists from stackoverflow page , for that I am clicking on inspect on the first question & i can see classname as **`question-hyperlink`** but when I try in the code below I get empty results , similarly if iI am trying with **divname summary** I get same empty results kindly guide on how can I fix this & avoid in future cases

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
website = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
r = requests.get(website)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Connected to {website}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    s = soup.find_all(class_name='question-hyperlink')
    print(s)
else:
    print(r)
    
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you're using doesn't have any questions - https://stackoverflow.com shows only a starting page, unless you're logged in.

You need to change the url to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`.

Also, you should be using `class_=`, not `class_name=` in `find_all()`.

Then it works just fine.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
}
r = requests.get(website, headers=headers)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Connected to {website}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="question-hyperlink")
    print(len(soup))
```

Output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

You focused on the class name 'question-hyperlink'. Within beautiful soup you can simply write something like `soup.find_all('div', class_='summary')`
to get a specific class.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python'


#A function that gets the H3 titles for the python tagged stackoverflow
#It saves and outputs a list with all the titles


def main():
    #get all elements from the entire page
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    questions = soup.find_all('div', class_='summary')
    
    #only get me the H3 html tags
    question_text = []
    for question in questions:
        question_text.append(question.find('h3').text)
    print(question_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Output: ['How do I verify if certificate is ca trusted in python?',...]
```